# Attribute many ids to single from other tables JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mysql-workbench

[image]

I want to create entity USERS_GROUP to link some user_ids to group_id.
I guess I overthink this case and now I can't find a solution.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserGroups> userGroups;
```

```
@Table(name = "groups")
@Data
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private String groupId;

    private String category;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
    private List<UserGroups> userGroups;
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "user_groups")
public class UserGroups {

    @EmbeddedId
    UserGroupsCompositeKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("userId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Users user;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("featureId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Group group;
```

```
@Embeddable
public class UserGroupsCompositeKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    String userId;

    @Column(name = "group_id")
    String groupId;
}
```

I want to sent POST requests like "/group/{group_id}/users"
to send in request body some lists of user_ids to connect them.

I think I overconfigured this solution with a composite key.
Is there some easier and more readable solution for that case ?

EDIT: This solution is not working as I want it to do.
I create jpaRepository class with CompositeKey (Not sure if it's correct way )

```
@Repository
public interface ProductFeaturesRepository extends JpaRepository<UserGroups, UserGroupsCompositeKey> {
}
```

And I want to add some Controller method to group class to add some users to group with request body like:

```
Endpoint:/group/{group_id}/users
Body:
[
  {
    "userId": "USER-NR423423534634"
  },
  {
    "userId": "USER-NR2355321"
  }
]
```

It's not working properly nothing is added to database after that request

Comment: does this work? If it works then you are good to go. I have done something similar in the past and it was in that direction.

Comment: This should be fine. You can check on the `FetchType` for the relations(lazy vs eager)